# How do I scale my game to different aspect ratios?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, game-development, screen-size

I'm totally new to Unity and programming in general, so please talk to me like I'm a total idiot (because I am one).

I'm making a brick breaker game for android (my first ever game). I've made it specifically for my phone which has a 1440x3200 screen but I want it to scale to any screen size.

My solution for the walls at the sides and top of the screen was to make them really long and then I used some code that I found online to anchor them to the sides and top of the screen. That's probably not the proper way to do things but it works.

The problem I'm facing now though, is that if I change the size of the screen, the bricks remain the same size and distance apart. How can I make the bricks and distance between them scale with the screen size?

This is what I have tried so far but it doesn't work at all...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float xModifier;
    private float yModifier;
    private Vector3 scale;
    private Vector3 newScale;

    void Start()
    {
        scale = transform.localScale;
        xModifier = Screen.width / 1440f;
        yModifier = Screen.height / 3200f;
        newScale = new Vector3(scale.x * xModifier, scale.y * yModifier, scale.z);
        transform.localScale = newScale;
    }
}
```

[1440 x 3200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFEyk.jpg)
[1440 x 2560](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq0ot.jpg)

Comment: Tiy would probably be better keeping your game physically the same size and just changing the render of the camera

Comment: @Jay So how do I do that dynamically for any screen size?

Answer (score 2):

That depends:

If your using 2D elements on a canvas, then you can just use [The Canvas Scaler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flmjH.png) to set UI Scale Mode: **Scale With Screen Size**

Otherwise you may want to use: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html
to force your preferred resolution